# Markdown Footnotes

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I've recently starting writing academic work in markdown format for a number of reasons and I am so far very happy with everything except I am confused about footnotes.

I use OSCOLA referencing - footnotes at the bottom of each page with a bibliography at the end of the work.

How can I best implement this in MD? I am using the Atom for editing and preview.

Comment: Markdown has no concept of "pages" so there is no way to place footnotes on a specific page. All footnotes go at the end of the document. That's your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandoc` has a built-in reference manager, `pandoc-citeproc`. See the [manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations). You'll need a bibliography file in a supported format, for instance `bibtex`. You can then use the `@refkey` syntax to cite a reference in your markdown. Finally, you'll need to compile your document using a relevant csl style. In your case, it seems like there is [a `csl` file implementing OSCOLA](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=OSCOLA).

So, first create a reference file; here would be `example.bib` with one reference:

```
@book{kelsen1945general,
  title={General theory of law and state},
  author={Kelsen, Hans},
  year={1945},
  publisher={The Lawbook Exchange, Ltd.}
}
```

Then, in your markdown file `example.md`, use `@refkey`:

```
Hans Kelsen states in an influential book[@kelsen1945general] that...
```

Download the OSCOLA style and put it in your path (for instance `~/.csl/` on unix.

```
wget https://www.zotero.org/styles/oscola -O ~/.csl/oscola.csl
```

Finally, compile with pandoc and relevant options:

```
pandoc example.md -o example.pdf --bibliography=example.bib --csl=oscola.csl --citeproc
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry I can only upvote this once.

So is there a way when the document is compiled I can get the footnotes on each outputted page?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the default with pdf and docx outputs. For html, it doesn't make sense as there is no concept of page, as the previous commenter pointed out.

Comment: That's excellent, just needed to know that when I turn in a PDF or .docx it will have footnotes. Thank you so much for your answer :)